# Powershell regular expression to replace a digit with a string of variable length

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, expression

I have the following string

```
$FileNamePattern =  'blah_{4}_{5}_blah_{4}-{2}.CSV'
```

and I want to replace the numbers in the curly braces with a string of question marks, n characters long

As an example I would like it to return `'blah_????_?????_blah_????-??.CSV'`

I have this so far, but can't seem to get the 'expansion' in the replace working

```
[regex]::Replace($FileNamePattern,'{(\d+)}','"?"*$1')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Matthew

Comment: Try backslash the curly braces of your regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the processing of the match inside a callback method:

```
$callback = {  param($match) "?" * [int]$match.Groups[1].Value }
$FileNamePattern =  'blah_{4}_{5}_blah_{4}-{2}.CSV'
$rex = [regex]'{(\d+)}'
$rex.Replace($FileNamePattern, $callback)
```

The regex `{(\d+)}` matches `{` and `}` and captures 1+ digits in between. The submatch is parsed as an integer inside the callback (see `[int]$match.Groups[1].Value`) and then the `?` is repeated that amount of times with `"?" * [int]$match.Groups[1].Value`.

[image]